# No display of CTAN documentation of a package in pdf format on smartphones

Tags: discussion

I use a low-medium range smartphone. I don't understand why when I log on to CTAN and want to download a pdf this doesn't happen. What is the reason?

Comment: I found that sometimes you have to use multiple tries. Instead, it's not a problem when visiting `texdoc.net/pkg/<pkg>`.

Comment: @Werner Thank you very much. For my opinion your it is an answer. Can you commute, please, in a answer (more complete) that upvoted you? THKS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When viewing content on CTAN, linking to files is done through mirroring, which poins to some readily-available server for the actual content. This mirroring may target servers that don't respond fast enough, possibly dropping the query. One way around it is to use a dedicated server. In the case of documentation (or PDFs), this is provided by `https://texdoc.net/pkg/<pkg>` (where `<pkg>` represents the package you're interested in). The server finds the closest match to `<pkg>`. For those packages with multiple documentation versions (which might be in different formats, or separate documentation for code and user interfaces, say), you're still forced to go the CTAN route.

Comment: Thank you \infty for your answer.